# distinguishing between a changing incidence and baseline variability

Tags: correlation, biostatistics, epidemiology

This is a basic epidemiology question. Please forgive my ignorance.

I have a data set - the yearly incidences of a (rare) disease over an 11 year period.

Plotting these values on a graph, it is difficult to tell whether the incidence is increasing or just randomly varying, year on year. The value in year 11 is higher than the value in year 1, but the value in year 10 is towards the lower end of the range, and the highest value of all is in year 3.

I want to work out if this data actually does suggests that the incidence is increasing over this 11 year period, or whether this could just be a random variation of the incidence of the disease, with it just so happening that the incidence in year 11 happened to be higher than the incidence in year one.

Is there a method or calculation that can be used to quantify the probability of there being or not being a true trend in a data set such as this?

For reference, here is the data:

(Incidences per 100,000 of population)

Incidence in Year 1 : 0.25

Incidence in Year 2 : 0.32

Incidence in Year 3 : 0.45

Incidence in Year 4 : 0.31

Incidence in Year 5 : 0.33

Incidence in Year 6 : 0.38

Incidence in Year 7 : 0.32

Incidence in Year 8 : 0.36

Incidence in Year 9 : 0.33

Incidence in Year 10 :  0.30

Incidence in Year 11 : 0.37